# Firebase query array 'in' limit of 10

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to exceed the limit of 10 on the [firebase query "in"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)?
Or any workaround with firebase function to receive the result?

The problem is we have a endless list that returns all documents.

```
{
   title: 'some title',
   filterID: '1',
},
{
   title: 'some title',
   filterID: '2',
},
{
   title: 'some title',
   filterID: '3',
},
{
   title: 'some title',
   filterID: '4',
},
...
```

Now we want to build a filter that the user can set and query with the "in" query.

```
const filter = ['1','2','3']
firestore.collection('feed').where('filterID', 'in', filter).valueChanges();
```

This works like we want but there are more filterID's than 10.
Should we restructure the data or exists a workaround with firebase functions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of 10 documents for an IN query a hard limit.  There is no structural change that will make this any easier for you.

What you should do instead is simply `get()` each document individually, or establish a listener on each one.